# Set values in 2D-array by index (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I define my 2D-array as followed

```
var row = 4
var col = 4
val myArray = Array(row) { IntArray(col) }

fun fillArray(myArray: Array<IntArray>) {
    myArray.forEach {
        it.forEach {
            var random = (1..4).random()
            myArray.set(i, random)
            Log.i(TAG, random.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I have two Problems in the line

```
myArray.set(i, random)
```

**First:**
how can i get the current index "i" of the 2D-Array Element

**Second:**
the function does not take the random generated number "random". The IDE says the type IntArray is needed.
I understand that i generated an array with int types, but i want to set a value of the type int and not IntArray so i dont quite understand what i shoul do.

If i access the value directly by index this way

```
numbers[0][0] = 3
```

everything is fine. But if i iterate over it as i showed above i cant set a value for each index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know the `numbers[0][0] = 3` syntax, just use that. The loops should go through the `indices` of `myArray` and the `indices` of each inner array.

```
for (outerIndex in myArray.indices) {
    for (innerIndex in myArray[outerIndex].indices) {
        myArray[outerIndex][innerIndex] = (1..4).random()
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer `forEach`:

```
myArray.indices.forEach { outerIndex ->
    myArray[outerIndex].indices.forEach { innerIndex ->
        myArray[outerIndex][innerIndex] = (1..4).random()
    }
}
```

Note that you should not `forEach` over the array. That goes over the *elements* of the array, but the original elements of the array is of no use to you, since the whole point of this is to fill the array with random values.

In fact, you could also have initialised the array with random values like this:

```
val myArray = Array(row) { 
    IntArray(col) { (1..4).random() } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray.set(i, random)
```

This call doesn't work from quite an obvious reason. The type of `myArray` is `Array<IntArray>` (so it's kind of `Array<Array<Int>>`). So, you cannot set an `Integer` when `IntArray` is expected.

To fix it (I am using named parameters to make it clearer) you need to use `forEachIndexed`:

```kotlin
fun fillArray(myArray: Array<IntArray>) {
    myArray.forEach { outerArray ->
        outerArray.forEachIndexed { innerIndex, _ ->
            val random = (1..4).random()
            
            outerArray.set(innerIndex, random) // we should use different syntax ("Should be replaced with indexing")
            outerArray[innerIndex] = random // this is proper syntax
        }
    }
}
```